# Bash: Copy indexed files, keeping file index

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files named like this:

```
my-file_0.png
my-file_1.png
my-file_1.png
...
```

Now I want to copy all these files to a set of new files, with a new prefix, but the same index number. Something like this:

```
my-file_0.png -> new-file_0.png
my-file_1.png -> new-file_1.png
my-file_2.png -> new-file_2.png
...
```

Any nice idea for a short Bash script to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  Show us some of your code that's not working so we can help improve what you've done thus far.  Otherwise,  `man cp`and [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can it **only one command**

```
for f in my-file* ; do mv $f ${f/my-file/new-file} ; done
```

${f/my-file/new-file} replace "my-file" to "new-file" in variable f.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I prefer this solution because it doesn't require me to define the number of files upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop in bash over the indices.

```
for i in $(seq 0 2); do cp my-file_${i}.png new-file_${i}.png; done
```